# Drop the first few hours timeseries data in pandas without hard coding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Suppose I have a pandas TimeSeries Dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quote_ts': ['2020-05-15 14:01:00.522517', 
                                '2020-05-15 14:01:00.599999', 
                                '2020-05-15 15:00:01.234517',
                                '2020-05-16 14:00:00.312518',
                                '2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517',
                                '2020-05-17 14:00:00.122983',
                                '2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567',
                                '2020-05-18 14:00:00.522517'],
                   'price': [1000, 1200, 1300, 1000, 1400, 1800, 1900, 1600]})

df = df.set_index('quote_ts')
```

I have multiple files of the same and I want to drop the first 12 hours of the data from the first time point available irrespective of where it starts from. I dont know what date or time the first data will be. So how do I make a general solution for the same?

I do not know how to approach this problem. I am aware of pandas.Series.between_time but I dont know the exact values.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `index` to datetime then create a boolean mask by comparing the datetime index against the (first value of index + offset of 12 hours) then use the resulting mask to filter rows

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df[df.index > df.index[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=12)]
```

Result

```
                            price
quote_ts                         
2020-05-16 14:00:00.312518   1000
2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517   1400
2020-05-17 14:00:00.122983   1800
2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567   1900
2020-05-18 14:00:00.522517   1600
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that my data has gaps in between, and after every period gap I need to do this dropping of 12 hours step. Can you recommend how to incorporate that as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like -

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'quote_ts': ['2020-05-15 14:01:00.522517', 
                                '2020-05-15 14:01:00.599999', 
                                '2020-05-15 15:00:01.234517',
                                '2020-05-16 14:00:00.312518',
                                '2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517',
                                '2020-05-17 14:00:00.122983',
                                '2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567',
                                '2020-05-18 14:00:00.522517'],
                   'price': [1000, 1200, 1300, 1000, 1400, 1800, 1900, 1600]})

df['quote_ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['quote_ts'])
df = df.set_index('quote_ts')

start = df.index[0] + pd.Timedelta('12H')
df = df[start:]
```

output for above case -

```
                            price
quote_ts                         
2020-05-16 14:00:00.312518   1000
2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517   1400
2020-05-17 14:00:00.122983   1800
2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567   1900
2020-05-18 14:00:00.522517   1600
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that my data has gaps in between, and after every period gap, I need to do this dropping of 12 hours step. Can you recommend how to incorporate that as well?